# How do you set the DisplayMemberPath for a List of Lists (at runtime)?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the below classes (abbreviated for simplicity):

```cs
namespace Test
{
    class Class1
    {
        Class2 Property2 { get; set; }
        Class3 Property3 { get; set; }
    }

    class Class2
    {
        string ColumnName { get; set; }
    }

    class Class3
    {
        string ColumnName { get; set; }
        bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I instantiate a list of `Class1` and populate it, then set the databinding of a `ListView` to my list as below.

```cs
List<Class1> pList = ...;
listView1.ItemsSource = pList;
```

I've tried to set `listView1.DisplayMemberPath` equal to `"ColumnName"`, `"Class2.ColumnName"`, `"Class3.ColumnName"`, `"Test.Class2.ColumnName"`, but nothing seems to work (the `ListView` displays blank items. If I set the `DisplayMemberPath` to a list of `Class2` or `Class3`, the `ListView` displays, but I'd like to keep a list of `Class1` as my 
datasource.

Is there anything simple I'm missing here (I'm assuming this is very possible)? (I've searched far and wide for a solution to my problem (which is hopefully really simple), but I haven't gotten anything to work yet.)

Comment: have you tried with `Property2.ColumnName` and `Property3.ColumnName`?

Comment: @Steve: This was it! It would certainly explain why the "property not found" error kept coming up, so that should have tipped me off in and of itself. If you make this an answer, I will definitely accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your internal classes are Property2 and Property3,
so I think that the right use for listView1.DisplayMemberPath is:

```
listView1.DisplayMemberPath = "Property2.ColumnName";
```

Answer (score 2):

DisplayMemberPath is just a shortcut.
You can always use the more flexible way of providing a DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2.ColumnName}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Going down the route of learning all of the XAML behind WPF is something I wanted to avoid for the time being and would probably obviate the need for this question, but I suppose if I keep going on this way, I'll ultimately end up going this way.

Comment: +1: Two weeks later and this is the approach I end up using. Thanks again for answering.